# net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: Column not found: 0

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am new for UCanAccess

```
package checktpsystemdatabase;

import java.sql.*;

public class CheckTPSystemDatabase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/Java/TransactionProcessingSystem/src/transactionprocessingsystem/Resources/TPSystem.accdb");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Product");

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(0) + "\t" + rs.getString(1) + "\t" + rs.getString(2));
            }
            rs.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, It is showing `"net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: Column not found: 0"`. Please help me!

Comment: Make sure product table has columns, do a describe product table and ascertain the columns.

Comment: yes the product table has columns, I don't know why the problem occurs!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing that error because the numeric index values for a JDBC ResultSet start with 1, not 0. Or, as they say in the "Retrieving Column Values from Rows" section of the Java Tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html):

> The ResultSet interface declares getter methods (for example, getBoolean and getLong) for retrieving column values from the current row. You can retrieve values using either the index number of the column or the alias or name of the column. The column index is usually more efficient. **Columns are numbered from 1**

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gord Thompson.
Now I am using column name rather than index and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

simply

the ResultSet rs begins with index 1 not 0 so you should write rs.getInt(1) or rs.getObject(1)