# Unexpected Token: AS (Using UCanAcces.jar)

Tags: java, database, connection, token, ucanaccess

I can't find the mistake, I get this error:

```
Error: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: unexpected token: = required: AS
```

This is my code. Can you help me find it? Thanks in advance.

```
package database;

// Imports
import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect {
// Path to Database
final static String DB = "jdbc:ucanaccess://src/database/DB.accdb";

// Declareren
public static String strAntwoord1;

public void Connect(){        
    // Initialiseren
    Connection con;
    Statement s;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    // Try Database Path/Connection to get Variables
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB); 
        s = con.createStatement();
        rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblAntwoorden WITH ID=1"); 

        if (rs != null) while ( rs.next() ) {
                strAntwoord1 = rs.getString("Antwoord");

                if (strAntwoord1 == "Indonesië"){
                    System.out.println("Antwoord found.");

                }

            }

        s.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);

    }

}

}
```

It's a task for school and I've got to solve this before midnight. So I've got 1 hour left. Thanks in advance for the people who are willing to help me.

Comment: What have you done to try to debug this problem already? Have you done a binary search in the code to find the problem? (that is, have you commented out lines and blocks of code to see which part causes the error)?

Comment: @verdammelt Yes, I did. It seems to be the SQL that gives the error but I can't seem to find a SQL mistake in that 1 sentence... The names of the tables and so forth are right so yeah... I'm kind off hopeless atm :p

Comment: Have you searched for other people's solutions to UcanaccessSQLException problems?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527054/net-ucanaccess-jdbc-ucanaccesssqlexception-column-not-found-0  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191830/java-error-net-ucanaccess-jdbc-ucanaccesssqlexception-malformed-string ...

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore Yes, but they don't have any problems that are in any way equal to mine... Sadly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benji, your SQL has to be perfectioned. Not WITH but WHERE:

```
SELECT * FROM tblAntwoorden WHERE ID=1
```

The message says "an alias declaration is expected", e.g.,

```
SELECT * FROM tblAntwoorden AS a WHERE a.ID=1
```

yet I hope this  suggestion from a different timezone  helps you to do the next  homework.

Comment: Well, seem to have 2 hours ledt to upload the task... Most stupid mistake I have ever made Thanks mate!